# How to use controls from built-in UITypeEditors?

Tags: c#, winforms, windows-forms-designer, uitypeeditor

I want to use "Select resource" dialog in my dropdown UITypeEditor for custom struct property.
I already have `TestEditorControl:UserControl`, which contains a `button1` with event handler for `Click`:

```
btn.Click+=(s,a)=>{
    OpenFileDialog oDlg = new OpenFileDialog();
    if (oDlg.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

How to replace "OpenFileDialog" with "Select resource" dialog?
I tried this code (based on [Visual Studio "Select Resource" dialog replacement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14952181/visual-studio-select-resource-dialog-replacement)):

```
private Form resDialog;
public TestEditorControl()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    var property = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(button1)["Image"];
    var resourceEditorSwitch = property.GetEditor(typeof(UITypeEditor)) as UITypeEditor;
    var editorToUseField = resourceEditorSwitch.GetType().GetProperty("EditorToUse",
        System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance |
        System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic);
    var editorToUse = editorToUseField.GetValue(resourceEditorSwitch);

    //System.NullReferenceException     (editorToUseField == null)

    var resourcePickerUIField = editorToUse.GetType().GetField("resourcePickerUI",
        System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance |
        System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic);
    var resDialog= (Form)Activator.CreateInstance(resourcePickerUIField.FieldType);
}

btn.Click+=(s,a)=>{
    if (resDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: The resource picker dialog is designed for design-time of VS, you cannot use it for run-time.

Comment: If you want to use if for design-time, it's enough to have an image property like `public Image MyImage { get; set; }`, then the designer will show resource picker dialog for this property.

Comment: @RezaAghaei, I want to use it for design time, but i want call this dialog from code (button1.Click event), not from PropertyGrid. My `TestControl:Control` has `TestProperty` with custom  `TestUIEditor:UITypeEditor`, that uses my `TestEditorControl`. I want use `TestEditorControl.button1` to pick image resource

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To show editor of a property, you need to get the [`UITypeEditor`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.design.uitypeeditor?view=net-5.0&WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235) of the property and call its [`EditValue`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.design.uitypeeditor.editvalue?view=net-5.0&WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235):

```
var editor = (UITypeEditor)propertyDescriptor.GetEditor(typeof(UITypeEditor));
var editedValue = editor.EditValue(context, provider, propertyValue);
```

The values you need to pass to the method, depend to the context of the code, in addition to the example in this post, I've shared a few other links at bottom of this post.

### Example - Show Select Image dialog for a nested property

In this example I have created a `MyTestControl`, which has a property called `MyTestProperty` which is of `MyTestClass` type, which has a `MyTestImage` property of `Image` type. I'm going to show a `UITypeEditor` for `MyTestProperty`, and a button inside the editor which shows select image dialog and changes the image property:

[image]

**The Control**

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.ComponentModel.Design;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Design;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Windows.Forms.Design;
public class MyTestControl : Control
{
    [Editor(typeof(MyTestClassEditor), typeof(UITypeEditor))]
    [DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Content)]
    public MyTestClass MyTestProperty { get; set; } = new MyTestClass();

    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnPaint(e);
        if (MyTestProperty != null &&
            MyTestProperty.MyTestImageProperty != null)
            e.Graphics.DrawImage(MyTestProperty.MyTestImageProperty,
                ClientRectangle.Location);
    }
}
public class MyTestClass
{
    public Image MyTestImageProperty { get; set; }
}
```

**UITypeEditor**

```
public class MyTestClassEditor : UITypeEditor
{
    public override UITypeEditorEditStyle GetEditStyle(
        ITypeDescriptorContext context)
    {
        return UITypeEditorEditStyle.DropDown;
    }
    public override object EditValue(ITypeDescriptorContext context, 
        IServiceProvider provider, object value)
    {
        var svc = (IWindowsFormsEditorService)provider
            .GetService(typeof(IWindowsFormsEditorService));
        var propertyToEdit = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(value)
            [nameof(MyTestClass.MyTestImageProperty)];
        var ctx = new TypeDescriptionContext(
            (Control)context.Instance, provider, value, propertyToEdit);
        var editorControl = new MyTestClassEditorControl(svc, ctx, provider);
        svc.DropDownControl(editorControl);
        return editorControl.Result;
    }
}
```

**Editor control**

```
public class MyTestClassEditorControl : Control
{
    public Object Result { get; private set; }
    public MyTestClassEditorControl(IWindowsFormsEditorService service,
        ITypeDescriptorContext context, IServiceProvider provider) 
    {
        Result = context.Instance;
        var button = new Button() { Text = "Choose Image",  AutoSize = true };
        button.Click += (sender, e) =>
        {
            try
            {
                var imageProp = context.PropertyDescriptor;
                var imageValue = imageProp.GetValue(context.Instance);
                var editor = (UITypeEditor)imageProp
                    .GetEditor(typeof(UITypeEditor));
                var selectedImage = editor.EditValue(
                    context, provider, imageValue);
                imageProp.SetValue(context.Instance, selectedImage);
                context.OnComponentChanging();
                context.OnComponentChanged();
                service.CloseDropDown();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
            }
        };
        this.Controls.Add(button);
        this.Height = 100;
    }
}
```

**TypeDescriptionContext**

```
public class TypeDescriptionContext : ITypeDescriptorContext
{
    Control control;
    IServiceProvider provider;
    object instannce;
    PropertyDescriptor property;
    public TypeDescriptionContext(Control control,
        IServiceProvider provider, object instannce,
        PropertyDescriptor property)
    {
        this.control = control;
        this.provider = provider;
        this.instannce = instannce;
        this.property = property;
    }
    public IContainer Container => control.Site?.Container;
    public object Instance => instannce;
    public void OnComponentChanged() =>
        GetService<IComponentChangeService>()
        ?.OnComponentChanged(control, null, null, null);
    public bool OnComponentChanging() => true;
    public PropertyDescriptor PropertyDescriptor => property;
    public object GetService(Type type) => provider?.GetService(type);
    public T GetService<T>() => (T)this.GetService(typeof(T));
}
```

### More example

You may want to look into following posts for more example:

- [Display Mask property editor](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36314635/3110834)
- [Display Multiline string property editor](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43826903/3110834)
- [Obtain ITypeDescriptorContext in designer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43827054/3110834)

Comment: Using VisualStudio 2022. I am unable to make this work. The same is true for your other example for the Mask property editor. Do you know if something changed between the VisualStudio versions? The property editor in VS is just showing "WinFormsApp1.MyTestClass" for the "MyTestProperty" without any kind of dropdown.

Comment: @DanielBürckner Above examples are for a .NET Framework project. For a .NET 5+ it might be different. What's your project type?

Comment: Windows Forms App - .Net 8.0.

Comment: @DanielBürckner It's a whole different story for .NET 5+ projects. The designer architecture is different. You can read more in this blog post: [Custom Controls for WinForm’s Out-Of-Process Designer](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/custom-controls-for-winforms-out-of-process-designer/?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235).

Comment: @DanielBürckner Take a look at this repo as well: [microsoft/winforms-designer-extensibility](https://github.com/microsoft/winforms-designer-extensibility); where you can find example for custom UiTypeEditor for out-of-proc designer.

Comment: Just in case you are interested to use the custom UI type editors only in run-time (For example showing on a form which is using a PropertyGrid to edit some properties) then it works without any change. Just make sure you put all classes explicitly in a namespace.

Comment: Thx @Reza Aghaei. I had a look at the article and the repo. Looks like a lot has changed when creating for example a simple mask editor for a custom control. Do you plan to migrate your examples to the new architecture somewhere in the future?